# Where to place 'input.json file' when do Google Cloud Machine Learning engine prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, predict

I am using Google Cloud ML Engine to do local prediction by run:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR --json-instances $INPUT_FILE --framework $FRAMEWORK
```

assume:

```
MODEL_DIR="gs://<bucket>/model.joblib"
FRAMEWORK="SCIKIT_LEARN"
```

input file `input.json` is in hardisk (d:\predict)

How to specify: `INPUT_FILE=`?

I have manually upload the input file into my gc bucket, but get error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) Unable to read file [gs://<bucket>/input.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://<bucket>/input.json
```

Where shall I place the input file?

shall I keep it as in local disk (e.g. `d:\predit\input.json`) or in bucket?

And what format is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `MODEL_DIR` wrong, there is no need of adding "model.joblib" as it will be detected automatically. `MODEL_DIR` should contain the path (including folders if necessary) where the file "model.joblib" is. As good practise, it's common to have a bucket containing it. The command (for your case) should go like this :

```
  MODEL_DIR="gs://<bucket>/"
  INPUT_FILE="input.json"
  FRAMEWORK="SCIKIT_LEARN"
```

and your bucket should contain "model.joblib". For `INPUT_FILE`, it should contain the path where "input.json" is FROM where you are running the command and the ".json" itself (i.e, if the ".json" it's under other folder, `INPUT_FILE` should be "< folder>/input.json").

Here is the documentation for testing models [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/deploying-models#test_your_model_with_local_predictions).

Comment: can you double check if you have the files in the bucket? You can do so running this `gsutil ls $MODEL_DIR` or by using the UI. I reproduced this myself and work fine for me. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've trying to get the same error you see, and I only get it when there file is not there. Sorry to insist on this, but do you have any folder or something where those files are? I.e, the files are under gs://<bucket>/predict (or any other folder). If that's the case, `MODEL_DIR` should be that path. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176623/discussion-between-inigo-and-frank).